# Sending COBOL record to Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, batch-processing, cobol

I have a COBOL batch program that needs to place messages into a Kafka topic.  I know that there are functions available to allow me to dump a file or DB2 table into a Kafka topic from the mainframe.  And I can accomplish this by having a two step job: 1.) Batch job runs and writes to file/table.  2.) Load file/table into Kafka topic from mainframe.

However, are there any new or existing technologies or functions available that will allow the placement of COBOL batch messages into a Kafka topic at/during runtime?

Comment: Can you call C/C++ functions? https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka

Comment: [tag:real-time] has a specific meaning in IT, and there is nothing relevant to it in this question. Don't tag indiscriminately, and don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @cricket_007 Current IBM Enterprise COBOL compilers can call C functions.  Whether the code you link to will build on z/OS is another question.

Comment: @cschneid Fair enough. How about exec out to a Golang/Rust binary? Same problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 I _think_ so, I'm unaware of compilers for those languages on IBM Z.  There's also the issue of "classic" z/OS batch vs. z/Unix batch or z/Linux batch.  There are many questions regarding the OP's requirements and environment.

Comment: Can you make HTTP calls from COBOL? You could then use the [REST proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) to send messages.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt there is a product from IBM called zOS Connect which allows you to call an IMS transaction as a REST/API and vice-versa.  And we are looking into that as well.  This would require a bit more infrastructure set-up than a direct interface to Kafka from zOS. I want to take the path of least resistance.  At the moment it would be easier to use COBOL -> message -> MQ <- Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin, you can now run Apache Kafka directly on z/OS via the z/OS Container Extensions (zCX). zCX is a standard, fully supported feature included in the base z/OS 2.4 operating system at no additional charge, and it runs on any IBM z14 (or higher) machine equipped with Feature Code 0104. (Many systems already have FC 0104 because it's required to run some other things besides zCX.) You would still connect to the Docker/OCI container running Kafka via TCP/IP in some fashion, but it's all virtual/memory-to-memory since Kafka can run in the same z/OS instance as your COBOL batch program.

If you don't yet have zCX you can still get ready for it. Just create and run your desired Docker/OCI containers, such as Kafka, on Linux on Z (or on a LinuxONE machine), and then you can move those containers, unmodified, to zCX when you're ready. And if you don't have a Linux on Z (or LinuxONE) environment to work with you can get one, at no charge for up to 120 days, from the IBM LinuxONE Community Cloud.

Yes, you can use MQ for z/OS, and that's a terrific choice. You'd need the MQ client in your Kafka container, but there's no additional charge for MQ clients assuming you have any of the currently IBM supported MQ versions for z/OS. A big advantage with MQ is the Q (queuing), generally a good fit with batch programs so that they can chug along and feed Kafka asynchronously. z/OS Connect Enterprise Edition is another good choice if you want synchronous interactions.

Another possible choice that's available at no additional charge in the base z/OS 2.1 (or higher) operating system is the z/OS Client Web Enablement Toolkit. This toolkit allows COBOL (and other) programs running on z/OS to make outbound REST API calls. It's not as functionally rich as z/OS Connect Enterprise Edition, and it's only unidirectional (supports requests from a z/OS hosted program to a REST API that's provided by a service running anywhere, which could be on z/OS itself, as with a Kafka REST API in zCX), but it may still meet or exceed your needs. You can find more information about this toolkit, including a COBOL example, here:

https://github.com/IBM/zOS-Client-Web-Enablement-Toolkit